# Images not displaying on Safari (Wordpress + W3 Total Cache)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, w3-total-cache

Our website runs the latest version of Wordpress
We have Woocommerce installed
We have W3 Total Cache installed.

On Safari Browser, images through the product content on Woocommerce are not displaying. Product image also not displaying.
Not displaying on Safari only.
When I disable W3 Total Cache plugin, images load fine.
I go through each of W3 Total Cache core settings disabling/enabling them and still no luck.

I using 5.1.7 safari user agent - I add user agent string to rejected user agents in W3 total cache and still images are not displayed.

Does anyone know if this is a common issue? I disable all other plugins and have narrowed down to being just w3 total cache not working properly with Woocommerce on Safari. 
Images work fine on all browsers except safari.

Any advise much appreciated. CDN doesnt make any difference. I use CDN on live site, and no CDN on test site, but issue still persist.

Images are there just not being displayed.
I can right click on where the images should be, and get context menu with image information such as copy image address. The images are there but not displaying

Thanks in advance.